# Cannot call a function from the same scope

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I'm confused about the scope. I downloaded a Fortran file which has 1 main program, 1 subroutine and 1 function in 1 source file. The main program does not contain the subprograms, and the function is called by the subroutine. It works fine, but when I modified the main program to contain those 2 subprograms using "contains", it gives compile error, saying the function is not defined. However, if I create a small function within the same contained section and call from the subroutine, it does not give an error.

What is the difference between those 2 functions? Why do I get the error?

I created a small program with the same structure, 1 main that contains a subroutine and a func and it did not give an error.

My environment is ubuntu 14.04 and using gfortran compiler.

---

Building target: QRbasic
Invoking: GNU Fortran Linker
gfortran  -o "QRbasic"  ./main.o
./main.o: In function `qrbasic':
/*/QRbasic/Debug/../main.f95:79: undefined reference to`ajnorm_'
/home/kenji/workspace/QRbasic/Debug/../main.f95:104: undefined reference to `ajnorm_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [QRbasic] Error 1

---

```
Program Main
!====================================================================
! QR basic method to find the eigenvalues
! of matrix A
!====================================================================
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n=3
double precision, parameter:: eps=1.0e-07
double precision :: a(n,n), e(n)
integer i, j, iter

! matrix A
!  data (a(1,i), i=1,3) /   8.0, -2.0, -2.0 /
!  data (a(2,i), i=1,3) /  -2.0,  4.0, -2.0 /
!  data (a(3,i), i=1,3) /  -2.0, -2.0, 13.0 /

  data (a(1,i), i=1,3) /   1.0,  2.0,  3.0 /
      data (a(2,i), i=1,3) /   2.0,  2.0, -2.0 /
  data (a(3,i), i=1,3) /   3.0, -2.0,  4.0 /


! print a header and the original matrix
  write (*,200)
  do i=1,n
     write (*,201) (a(i,j),j=1,n)
  end do
! print: guess vector x(i)
!  write (*,204)
!  write (*,201) (y(i),i=1,3)

  call QRbasic(a,e,eps,n,iter)

! print solutions
  write (*,202)
  write (*,201)  (e(i),i=1,n)
  write (*,205) iter

200 format (' QR basic method - eigenvalues for A(n,n)',/, &
            ' Matrix A')
201 format (6f12.6)
202 format (/,' The eigenvalues')
205 format (/,' iterations = ',i5)
!end program main

contains
subroutine QRbasic(a,e,eps,n,iter)
!==============================================================
! Compute all eigenvalues: real symmetric matrix a(n,n,)
! a*x = lambda*x
! method: the basic QR method
! Alex G. (January 2010)
!--------------------------------------------------------------
! input ...
! a(n,n) - array of coefficients for matrix A
! n      - dimension
! eps    - convergence tolerance
! output ...
! e(n)   - eigenvalues
! iter   - number of iterations to achieve the tolerance
! comments ...
! kmax   - max number of allowed iterations
!==============================================================
implicit none
integer n, iter
double precision a(n,n), e(n), eps
double precision q(n,n), r(n,n), w(n), an, Ajnorm, sum, e0,e1
integer k, i, j, m
integer, parameter::kmax=1000

! initialization
q = 0.0
r = 0.0
e0 = 0.0

do k=1,kmax              ! iterations

! step 1: compute Q(n,n) and R(n,n)
! column 1
  an = Ajnorm(a,n,1)
  r(1,1) = an
  do i=1,n
    q(i,1) = a(i,1)/an
  end do
! columns 2,...,n
  do j=2,n
    w = 0.0
    do m=1,j-1
! product q^T*a result = scalar
      sum = 0.0
      do i=1,n
        sum = sum + q(i,m)*a(i,j)
      end do
      r(m,j) = sum
! product (q^T*a)*q  result = vector w(n)
      do i=1,n
        w(i) = w(i) + sum*q(i,m)
      end do
    end do
! new a'(j)
    do i =1,n
      a(i,j) = a(i,j) - w(i)
    end do
! evaluate the norm for a'(j)
    an = Ajnorm(a,n,j)
    r(j,j) = an
! vector q(j)
    do i=1,n
      q(i,j) = a(i,j)/an
    end do
  end do

! step 2: compute A=R(n,n)*Q(n,n)
  a = matmul(r,q)
! egenvalues and the average eigenvale
  sum = 0.0
  do i=1,n
    e(i) = a(i,i)
    sum = sum+e(i)*e(i)
  end do
  e1 = sqrt(sum)

! print here eigenvalues
!  write (*,201)  (e(i),i=1,n)
!201 format (6f12.6)

! check for convergence
  if (abs(e1-e0) < eps) exit
! prepare for the next iteration
  e0 = e1
end do

iter = k
if(k == kmax) write (*,*)'The eigenvlue failed to converge'
 print *, func1()
end subroutine QRbasic

function Ajnorm(a,n,j)
implicit none
integer n, j, i
double precision a(n,n), Ajnorm
double precision sum

sum = 0.0
do i=1,n
  sum = sum + a(i,j)*a(i,j)
end do
Ajnorm = sqrt(sum)
end function Ajnorm

integer function func1()
print *, "dummy"
func1=1
end function

end program
```

The original program did not contain those 2 programs. This is the version I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main program contains a declaration of the type of function `Ajnorm()`.  As a result, when the compiler finds that name to be used as a function name, it interprets it as an *external* function.  That's quite correct in the original form of the program, with the function defined as an independent unit, but it is wrong for an internal (contained) function.  Your program compiles cleanly for me once I remove the unneeded declaration.